# How to Create and Apply a Tagging Policy in azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-policy

I want to create a policy that ensures all indexed resources are tagged. This will help us with organization and tracking, and make it easier to log when things go wrong.

In detail, how do you create a policy that ensures all indexed resources in your subscription have tags and deny deployment if they do not. I'd love to possibly do this from the CLI.

Any help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean exactly by "all indexed" resources.  There are canned policies for tags [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies).  The first several policies 'modify' resources or resource groups to add tags to existing, the last few policies will deny the creation of a resource or RG if a tag is not present.  The links will take you directly to the policies in the Azure Portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-policies

Comment: I think this addresses the issue, thanks!